# Opencart module ajax difficulty

Tags: javascript, ajax, opencart

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.brand select').on('change', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=module/brand_model/models',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {manufacturer_id: $(this).val()},
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.brand select').attr('disabled', true);
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('.brand select').attr('disabled', false);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data['models']) {
                    $('.model select').html(data['models']);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $('.model select').live('change', function(){
        if ($('.brand select').val() && $(this).val()) {
           var url = '<?php echo $this->url->link('module/brand_model/search','');
           ?>&filter_manufacturer_id='+$('.brand select').val()+'&filter_model='+$(this).val();
            window.location.href = url; 

        }

    });
});
```

How do i make window.location.href not to redirect to specific url, but load content of specific div from url var to display without refreshing page. i tried with $("#mydiv").load(url) instead of window.location.href but no success. It display blank content in #mydiv.

Comment: I get it with this:  $(function() {     
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'html',
        success: function(content,code) {
            $('body').html(content);
        }
    });        
});

Comment: what your ' var url = ' return ?

Comment: the products of selected brand.

Comment: I mean how your string values are, may be you can manipulate and show it to  page

Comment: i resolved this, with that array.. now i need to know how can i add a image loader and a fade..

Comment: Without any structure of the data that you are receiving from the ajax call, how we can help you with this?